# Android Studio reload application inside application

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, reset

I've got an application which crashes when it is resumed. The application can go into the pause phase just fine, but once it is resumed, the application simply crashes.

I want to make the application be able to restart itself when it is resumed. I don't want a full application reset where all data is purged, the application is closed, and then relaunched, I just want something which causes the application to "create" itself again.

My idea is to have something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    application.restart();
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this, and haven't found anything online.

Thanks!

Nathan

Comment: It's better if you debug your app..., find the origin of crash and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where my issue was. I had invoked `playSound.release();` inside of `onPause() { ... }` therefore causing the mediaPlayer I have running to shut itself down. I just had to make the mediaPlayer have the correct file put into it inside of the `onResume() { ... }` method.

Thanks to Rami for pointing me to look at the stack again. This time, I managed to find the problem to be in the mediaPlayer. Took another look at the mediaPlayer properties and found where the issue was.

Thanks!